# Use Python Argparse with several subparsers

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

Hi I am trying to configure argparse with several subparsers which are only accepting specific long arguments. Here below is the code

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='program', description='Prog Description')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='choices')
parser.add_argument('--choice', '-c', choices=['a', 'apple', 'b', 'banana', 'l', 'lemmon', 'p', 'papaya'], type=str, help='Menu Choices', required=True)
a_parser = subparsers.add_parser("a")
b_parser = subparsers.add_parser("b")
l_parser = subparsers.add_parser("l")
p_parser = subparsers.add_parser("p")

a_parser.add_argument("--peel")
b_parser.add_argument("--peel")
l_parser.add_argument("--lamount")
p_parser.add_argument("--pamount",required=True,type=str)
```

But I am failing at following points.

- subparsers should accept both short form and long forms. ex. `prog -c a` and `prog -c apple` are both legal and same
- argumens for subparsers are not required except for the `--pamount`. But code seem to be expecting them as I am getting following error when running a valid mode `python prog -c a`

  usage: program [-h] --choice {a,apple,b,banana,l,lemmon,p,papaya}
                 {a,p,b,l} ...
  program: error: too few arguments

I am glad if anyone could provide me some guidelines to resolve those problems. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

By using `subparsers` you don't need the `--choice` optional.

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='choice', help='choices')
# parser.add_argument('--choice', '-c', choices=['a', 'apple', 'b', 'b ...
```

Specify the `dest` to define a slot in the `args` for the subparser name (see the docs).

When you use `'python prog -c a'`, it parses the `a` as argument to `-c`; but it still expects a string like `a` as argument to the `subparsers` (which is in effect a positional argument).  Hence the error.  (In other words, it's not expecting the `--peel` argument; it hasn't gotten that far in the parsing.)

```
python prog a
python prog a --peel 3
```

should work.

```
python prog p --pamount 1
```

should also work (the --pamount is required).

To accept both 'a' and 'apple' as subparser names use the `aliases` parameter (see docs for `add_parser`).

```
a_parser = subparsers.add_parser("a", aliases=['apple','apples','manzana'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it was really helpful in figuring out the approach. However the error is still there as just now I checked that the `aliases` are new in Python 2.7 and I am using Python 2.6 and have to use it in that version. Also when I add  `dest='choice'` I cant add short form `c` in to the arguments.

Comment: You should be able to steal the `argparse.py` file from any 2.7 python and put in your own directory.

Comment: yes I am going to do a similar thing as current argparse module version is 1.2.1 and I will upgrade it to 1.4.1. This should solve the problem. :)